# How to change the page orientation?

Tags: corel-draw

I'm having difficulty changing the page orientation of one page from landscape to portrait, while keeping other pages as landscape.

Is there anyway that this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Corel you're running, but I imagine earlier/later versions have a similar option.  In CorelDRAW 2017, select Layout > Page Setup... :

[image]

Adjust the width/height as necessary, and check the "Apply size to current page only" box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This has certainly helped. My version of CorelDraw is X7

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Just select the current page option

[image: See little red arrow]